Error with Azure app service plan deployment
I am trying to create an app service plan (B3) on Azure West Europe location. This gets me the error

Code: Conflict No available instances to satisfy this request. App
Service is attempting to increase capacity. Please retry your request
later.  If urgent, this can be mitigated by deploying this to a new
resource group.

This is happening on and off for a week. It is a new resource group and a new service plan, however, we have a lot of similar service plans in our subscription.
I tried troubleshooting by deploying to a different-named resource group and this works, however, this is not what I want as we have naming conventions. Even when deleting the entire resource group, then redeploying, gives me the above error. What is going on?
EDIT:
After a weekend of success the problem is now back in full force. I am getting flustered as this costs me a lot of time and I can show no results while this error is here.
What I tried:

deploying with B2 instead of B3 => same error
deploying to a different named resource group => used to work last week, but now gives the same error.
checking quotas => nothing is above 10% utilization, besides the fact that I have no idea what I should be looking for in this list.
deploying the exact same thing directly from the portal, resulting in the same message.
deploying the exact same thing in the portal from the account of a colleague works! This is not what I expected. Our pipelines and my own account have the error, but a colleague does not? I do not understand this at all.


Have you been able to successfully deploy other App Service Plans, especially B3, in the West Europe region recently, or has this issue been happening every time you try to deploy.

Can you provide more detailed error logs or screenshots of the error message from the Azure Portal

Yes, I can deploy other B3s, but this is inconsistent. I get this error intermittently on different resource groups. Your other question @SirraSneha, I actually got this error from bicep deployment, I decided to try directly from portal, and the error was just the same.

Regarding your latest update about a colleague's account, could you raise a technical support ticket for that? That sounds like an investigatable problem.


Code: Conflict No available instances to satisfy this request. App Service is attempting to increase capacity. Please retry your request later. If urgent, this can be mitigated by deploying this to a new resource group.

The error message you’re encountering occurs because,

Azure regions like West Europe can run out of resources temporarily when there’s high demand, especially for popular tiers like B3
Even new resource groups can still face capacity problems if the region is busy, or the App Service Plan tier is popular.

To resolve the issue

Check Subscription Quotas: Verify that your subscription hasn’t reached its resource or regional quota limits:


Go to Azure Portal > Subscriptions > Usage + Quotas.
Check if there are any constraints specific to the region or resource type (e.g., App Service Plans).



Try deploying with a lower tier like B2 or S1 first, then upgrade to B3 later if needed.
Refer this DOC for Azure app service limits, quotas and constrains.
Azure regions scale automatically, but this can take time. If your deployment is not time-sensitive, try redeploying later.
Refer this DOC for distributing workloads across regions and using autoscaling effectively can help prevent capacity-related deployment issues.


Thank you for your answer @Naveen, I know about these quota. Which quotum would apply to the app service plan? There are long lists without any mention of app service plans. We are using app service with docker containers.

I just checked all quota and none of them are at 100%, I don't think the quota are the problem.

After doing nothing for a couple of days the problem seems to have gone away. Unfortunately there is no way for me to tell what caused it or what solved it. If I had to take a guess, it would be the automatic region scaling mentioned by Naveen.

And now the problem is back again. The trigger seems to be deleting the resource group.

@user1606815, as Naveen mentioned, Azure regions scale automatically, which is probably why it worked after a few days. Since the issue is back, try checking Azure Service Health to see if there are any ongoing problems in the West Europe region.

@user1606815, if West Europe keeps having capacity issues, you could try deploying to a nearby region like North Europe, if it meets your requirements. This might help avoid the temporary problems and allow your deployment to go through smoothly.
